# for-each-group and sort (but ignore some values)

Tags: xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

Consider this source XML:

```
<root>
  <value price="50">
    <type name="bike"/>
    <interesting value="no"/>
  </value>
  <value price="1">
    <type name="car"/>
    <interesting value="no"/>
  </value>
  <value price="123">
    <type name="bike"/>
    <interesting value="yes"/>
  </value>
  <value price="234">
    <type name="bike"/>
    <interesting value="yes"/>
    <pedals madeof="gold" />
  </value>
  <value price="150">
    <type name="car"/>
    <interesting value="yes"/>
  </value>
</root>
```

Now I'd like to group all bikes and all cars together but the order should be the  price (cheap to expensive) but only considering the bikes and cars with `<interesting value="yes"/>`.

My XSLT is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <out>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="value" group-by="type/@name">
        <xsl:sort select="@price" data-type="number"/>
        <elt>
          <xsl:attribute name="grouping-key" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
          <xsl:attribute name="min-price" select="@price"/>
        </elt>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </out>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which ignores the filtering for `<interesting value="yes"/>`. The result is

```
<out>
   <elt grouping-key="car" min-price="1"/>
   <elt grouping-key="bike" min-price="50"/>
</out>
```

but it should be

```
<out>
   <elt grouping-key="bike" min-price="123"/>
   <elt grouping-key="car" min-price="150"/>
</out>
```

because the `bike[interesting/@value='yes']` is cheaper than the `car[interesting/@value='yes']`

There can be more than two types of each vehicle and more entries with `interesting="yes"`.

How can I sort by the price but consider only those which are “interesting”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is probably more complicated than it should be, but here it is:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="value" group-by="type/@name">
   <xsl:sort select="not(empty(current-group()[interesting[@value = 'yes']]))" order="descending"/>
   <xsl:sort select="(min(current-group()[interesting[@value = 'yes']]/xs:integer(@price)), min(current-group()/xs:integer(@price)))[1]" data-type="number"/>

   <xsl:variable name="sorted-items" as="node()*">
      <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()">
         <xsl:sort select="interesting[@value = 'yes']" order="descending"/>
         <xsl:sort select="@price" data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:perform-sort>
   </xsl:variable>

   <elt>
      <xsl:attribute name="grouping-key" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="min-price" select="$sorted-items[1]/@price"/>
   </elt>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution which works fine, until I have another 'interesting' entry for bike. See my revised question (I've inserted another section there). I get the error 'XTTE1020: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the @select attribute of xsl:sort'.

Comment: Sorry for the late 'accept', but thank you very much again for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just filter the elements you select in your `<xsl:for-each-group` by adding a predicate :

```
  <xsl:for-each-group select="value[interesting/@value='yes']" group-by="type/@name">
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<out>
   <elt grouping-key="bike" min-price="123"/>
   <elt grouping-key="car" min-price="150"/>
</out>
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it does not output anything when there are no *interesting* items.

Comment: @MaxToro - Is that really a problem? Only the OP can say for sure, but since "consider only those which are “interesting”" is in the question I would think the bigger problem would be including anything in the output that doesn't have `interesting/@value='yes'`. +1